# Clarification on full-stop punctuation usage in a sentence

Tags: punctuation

Kindly read the below sentences and confirm if I used the full-stop correctly.  Kindly ignore the purpose of these sentences and their meaning. I am mainly concerned about the usage of the full-stop punctuation.

The sentences under examination are as follows -

Sentence-1:
However, I would like to add this point - the first word which was written was almost readable as "feedback", but I didn't wanted to take a chance, so I added 
"(feedback)" next to the first previous word which is "feedback".

Sentence-2:
Let us say that the correct answer to a question is "feedback", but the examinee writes it as "feedback (feedback)" on the answer sheet when the instruction to the question says that - "write one word". Now, the clarification is that - will this answer be marked as correct?

Comment: Not sure what is the sentence under examination.

Comment: @NVZ, the content after the sentence - "The sentence under examination:".

Answer (score 1):

From *The Chicago Manual of Style*, 16th edition, section 6.9:

> Periods and commas precede closing quotation marks, whether double or single.

However,

> In an alternative system, sometimes called British style, single quotation marks are used, and only those punctuation points that appeared in the original material should be included within the quotation marks; all others follow the closing quotation marks.

Depending on your location, you either need to change your double quotation marks to single or place your commas and periods inside them.

Comment: Peter Schilling, thanks for your answer. I was looking for a thumb-rule, and it seems I have it now, with your answer.